# Rewrite module not working

Tags: module, overrides, mod-rewrite

I just cant figure out where im going wrong.. can someone tell me?

app/etc/modules/Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Made_Streamcheckout />
            </depends>
        </Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Mynamespace/CheckoutOverrides/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <streamcheckout>
                <rewrite>
                    <url>Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides_Model</url>
                </rewrite>
            </streamcheckout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Mynamespace/CheckoutOverrides/Model/Streamcheckout.php

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides_Model_Streamcheckout extends Made_Streamcheckout_Model_Streamcheckout
{

    public function saveAll($data)
    {
        mage::log('works');        
    }

}
```

What am i missing here? :/

The streamcheckout config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Made_Streamcheckout>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </Made_Streamcheckout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <streamcheckout_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Made_Streamcheckout</module>
                </setup>
            </streamcheckout_setup>
        </resources>
        <models>
            <streamcheckout>
                <class>Made_Streamcheckout_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>streamcheckout_resource</resourceModel>
            </streamcheckout>
            <streamcheckout_resource>
                <class>Made_Streamcheckout_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <sales_order_additional>
                        <table>streamcheckout_sales_order_additional</table>
                    </sales_order_additional>
                    <sales_quote_additional>
                        <table>streamcheckout_sales_quote_additional</table>
                    </sales_quote_additional>
                </entities>
            </streamcheckout_resource>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <quote_address_total>Made_Streamcheckout_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total</quote_address_total>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>        
    </global>    
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model was wrong, use the whole class name.

**app/code/local/Mynamespace/CheckoutOverrides/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mynamespacecheckoutoverrides>
                 <class>Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides_Model</class>
            </mynamespacecheckoutoverrides>
            <streamcheckout>
                <rewrite>
                    <streamcheckout>Mynamespace_CheckoutOverrides_Model_Streamcheckout</streamcheckout>
                </rewrite>
            </streamcheckout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Do not forget to delete you Magento cache after this change**

Comment: Thank you! i edited my config, but sadly still doesnt work. Cleared cache many times, and looked for if module was active - it is. :/

Comment: Please add the config.xml of Streamcheckout extension and also the class you want to override.

Comment: I've edited my answer,  you have forgetten to declare your model class.

Comment: Ok, so now i have the exact same (except for the namespace replaced) .. is this the right tag for it? <mynamespacecheckoutoverrides>

Comment: I still cant get it to rewrite. I cleared my cache... so i just updated my first post with the config of streamcheckout. Does it make sense?

Comment: You forgot the code of the model you would like to override, thank you.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you so much!
So basically what i was doing wrong, was not declaring my model class?

Comment: Yes and also the <rewrite> has a problem.
You want to override class `Made_Streamcheckout_Model_Streamcheckout` but you digit `<url>`, so it means you were overriding `Made_Streamcheckout_Model_Url`.

Comment: AHH i think what really confused me was the <url> .. thank you so much, for your help!